# Do we have any supported liquibase plugins for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, liquibase

We are using Liquibase 3.8.5 version. Our requirement is to execute Liquibase script in Jenkins however we are not able to find out any Liquibase plugin in Jenkins.

Please let us know how to fix issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you integrate it into your Maven POM (or Ant Script or Gradle Script) you use to build your Java project?

Answer (score 1):

There's `Liquibase Runner Plugin` for Jenkins.

Here's a [github link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/liquibase-runner-plugin), but the last commit was 3 years ago, so I have no idea whether it's supported or not.

Also there's a `Liquibase command line`, perhaps it'll come in handy. https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/installation-linux-unix-mac.html

Comment: The new location is: https://plugins.jenkins.io/liquibase-runner/

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Liquibase+Runner

It adds to the build step which evaluated liquibase changesets.
Hope this helps

Comment: I have gone throught the link which you have provided however in Installation paragraph they are saying "Install the liquibase-runner plugin using Jenkins' plugin manager". But I can not find any Liquibase related plugin in Jenkins plugin manager. Please explain OR Is there any other approach to do that ?

Comment: New location is: https://plugins.jenkins.io/liquibase-runner/